# python matplotlib overlapping rectangles at certain size

Tags: python, matplotlib, overlapping

I'm trying to plot different rectangles with matplotlib which should have a little gap in between them like in following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle 
import numpy as np

Nmax = 200

xvalues = np.arange(Nmax)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

for xvalue in xvalues:
    rect = Rectangle(
        xy=(xvalue - 0.25, xvalue),
        width = 0.5,
        height = 1.5,
        facecolor = 'r',
        edgecolor = 'r',
        )
    ax.add_patch(rect)

ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

It's working as I would like to work for Nmax = 20 rectangles. Plot of Nmax=20 below:

[image]

As the rectangle positions are always 1 'unit' apart with a width of 0.5 there is always a spacing of 0.5 between two neighbouring rectangles.

However when I try it for example with 200 rectangles the rectangles get thicker and start overlapping. Upon zooming into the graph the rectangles are separated again. But saving the original figure as pdf still yields overlapping rectangles. Zoom of pdf with Nmax=200 below:

[image]

I don't know why this is happening, as I'm specifying still their widths to 0.5. I would be glad if someone could give me a hint on this.
I'm not sure but in a vector format it should be possible to determine the rectangle position exactly, so maybe saving it as svg and converting it to pdf would do the trick?

**Final solution:**
alright, thanks to zephyr the solution is to turn off the rectangle edge:

```
edgecolor = 'none',
```

Changing the edgecolor to 'none' in matplotlib.finance would also solve overlapping candlestick bars which seems to be the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296332/how-to-prevent-matplotlib-from-overlapping-ohlc-ticks)

Comment: Just a guess, but possibly the width refers to only the face width, not the face plus edge. If that is the case, the edge will always be the same size and contribute "padding" to your width that will only be noticeable on small scales. Try turning off the edge and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to zephyr the solution is to turn off the rectangle edge:

```
edgecolor = 'none',
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do want to use an `edgecolor` (that is, setting `edgecolor='none'` is not an option), you could produce a PDF which shows the space between boxes by increasing the `figsize` and `dpi` when creating the figure:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4), dpi=600)
```

If the `figsize` and `dpi` are big enough, the pdf-generating backend will display the whitespace between the rectangles:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle 
import numpy as np

Nmax = 200
xvalues = np.arange(Nmax)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4), dpi=600)
ax = plt.subplot(111)

for xvalue in xvalues:
    rect = Rectangle(
        xy=(xvalue - 0.25, xvalue),
        width = 0.5,
        height = 1.5,
        facecolor = 'r',
        edgecolor = 'r',
        )
    ax.add_patch(rect)

ax.autoscale_view()
# plt.show()
plt.savefig('/tmp/test.pdf')
```

Detail:

[image]

---

Another option is to reduce the linewidth when creating the Rectangle:

```
Rectangle(..., edgecolor='b', linewidth=0.01)
```

Comment: thanks, but I think that that's just a temporary workaround. Increasing the resolution leads to thinner edges, so they don't overlap. But with further increasing Nmax they will overlap again. So you could of course increase the figsize again but at some point you will run into memory problems.